# Redefine Median Filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I redefine median filter function instead of using the available function in Matlab? I want to smoothen my sound chart

Comment: Matlab doesn't allow you to do that. Why not just program your own filter, and call it `mymedianfilter` or something?

Comment: @MBaz though you'r right, Matlab allows you to do that as Carlos below explains...

Comment: @Fat32 I didn't know that. Sounds like a complex process, though. The only method I could get to work is private functions called from a file (not from the command line).

Answer (score 4):

You can shadow a built-in function as long as the newly defined function is higher on the [function precedence order](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html).

Note, however, that this is not recommended because:

1. It makes your code harder for someone else to understand
2. It makes your code harder to debug if something goes wrong

and plenty of other reasons.

As the commenter noted, it is usually better to just define a new function that does what you want with a different name.

EDIT:

If you are looking for specific ways to do something similar to a median filter, one place to look would be [pseudomedian filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudomedian).

Comment: ...but also, what this will achieve is to completely override the `median` for the particular session the "shadow" is in effect. Consequently, anything executed with the overridden `median` might have unpredictable behaviour. Which would be an additional reason for defining a new function.

Comment: @A_A yeah, it's pretty bad. But, the heart wants what it wants....

Comment: Without a doubt. I just felt it would be good to have that reminder as well. All the best